# Вставить или обновить данные MSSQL по определенному столбцу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста. Мне в таблицу нужно вставить строку по определенному критерию. Есть список магазинов(в таблице как номер), у каждого магазина есть своя категория (уникальная). Нужно, чтобы при вставке новой категории магазина проверялось: если у магазина уже есть такая категория, то обнови, если нет такой категории - то вставь.

Пример таблицы:

```
id  shop  category  address

1    7       1      Moscow
2    7       2      Kazan
3    7       3      Piter
4    10      1      Pscov
5    10      3      Novgorod
```

Например, я хочу вставить новый магазин с категорией "2" по столбцу "shop" - 7. В таблице уже есть такая категория у магазина "7", значит - update. Дальше, я хочу вставить новый магазин с категорией "2" по столбцу "shop" - "10". В таблице  нет еще такой категории у магазина "10", значит - insert.

Comment: *если у магазина уже есть такая категория, то обнови, если нет такой категории - то вставь.* [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510625%28v%3dsql.105%29)

Comment: И - с какой целью добавлен тег MySQL???